# NestJS "Validation failed (numeric string is expected)"

Tags: typescript, nest, class-transformer

I'm trying to create a PaginationDTO for using all across my app, and it behaves perfectly in all my controller methods except one.

Below endpoint is the one that throws error

***Validation failed (numeric string is expected)***

```
 @Get('bannedUsers')
    @ApiOperation({summary: "Banlanan kullanıcıların listesini getirir"})
    @Tags([PermissionTypes.USER_OPERATIONS, RoleRequestTypes.SERVICE])
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard, RoleGuard)
    async getBannedUsers(@Query() paginationDTO: PaginationDTO,) {
        return this.accountMicroservice.sendMicroserviceRequest("get-banned-users", paginationDTO)
    }
```

And this endpoint just works perfectly

```
 @Get('following/:id')
    @ApiOperation({summary: "Sicili girilen kullanıcının takip ettiklerini getirir"})
    @ApiParam({name: "id", description: "Takipçileri istenen kullanıcının sicili"})
    @Tags([PermissionTypes.DEFAULT, RoleRequestTypes.SERVICE, Utilities.ME])
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard, RoleGuard)
    async getUserFollowing(@Query() paginationDTO: PaginationDTO, @Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Promise<any> {
        const paginationDtoWithId: PaginationWithIdDTO = <PaginationWithIdDTO>{
            ...paginationDTO,
            id: id
        }
        return this.accountMicroservice.sendMicroserviceRequest("get-user-following", paginationDtoWithId)
    }
```

Difference between these two is *@Param* and also when i add @Param to endpoint above, it also works?

Here's my pagination DTO below

**PaginationDTO**

```
import {ApiProperty} from "@nestjs/swagger";
import {Transform} from "class-transformer";

export class PaginationDTO {

    @ApiProperty({type: () => Number})
    @Transform(({value}) => {
        const parsedValue = Number.parseInt(value);
        console.log("parsed: " + parsedValue)
        console.log(value);
        return !isNaN(parsedValue) ? parsedValue : 0;//new UnprocessableEntityException();
    })
    page: Number;

    @ApiProperty({type: () => Number})
    @Transform(({value}) => {
        const parsedValue = Number.parseInt(value);
        console.log("parsed: " + parsedValue)
        console.log(value);
        return !isNaN(parsedValue) ? parsedValue : 15;
    })
    limit: Number;
}
```

My application uses global validation pipe with transform option set to true. I can provide further info if needed. Thanks in advance.